# Can I load an iframe when user clicks on the facebook share thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, iframe

I am trying to do something like this:

1. A user share the url to my page which has a small javascript based lets-say-a-game.
2. The shared content will display a static image and a play button inside the widget/thumbnail.
3. When the user clicks on the play button, I want to load the page within the shared widget inside an iframe

For example: When a souncloud page is shared, it shows the music thumbnail and a play button. When I click on the play button it displays a javascript based music player inside the share widget loaded inside an iframe. To my understanding, the trick is to use a video content as a wrapper of some sort i.e swf but couldnt figure it out exactly how to do it.

Any help towards the right direction is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think Facebook will not allow you to post any script. Rather you can post links and if the user clicks on that link they will be redirected and there you can implement your code..

Comment: Any idea how soundcloud does it? They are not using a flash based music player but HTML/javascript so I think its possible. Thanks in any case :)